# How do I use only token authentication with Devise making sure no session/cookie mess is going on in the background

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, devise

I'm using Devise with Rails to power the user experience on an Android app. Due to this being an Android app, I won't be using any cookies or sessions. If I choose to pass and store something client-side, I will explicitly do that. Right now, I'm trying to test my Registrations and Sessions controllers, but noticed I run into sessions issues. Namely, I keep getting the `requires_no_authentication` which somehow spirals me to the Welcome to Rails page.

I figured out this is due to how `warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#failure"}` works.

If that is the case, then how do I make my Registrations and Sessions controllers work as I want?

I've come to the point where I feel like dumping Devise all together and making my own auth solution from scratch.

It seems my Registration works over and over because I don't use `warden.authenticate!` Once used, it messes with everything due to cookies/sessions.

These are my Registration and Session controllers at the moment:

**Session**

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  respond_to :json

  def create
    warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#failure")              

    render status: 200,
           json: { success: true,
                   info: "Logged in",
                   data: { auth_token: devise_current_user.authentication_token } }
  end

  def destroy
    warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#failure")

    current_user.update_column(:authentication_token, nil)

    render status: 200,
           json: { success: true,
                   info: "Logged out",
                   data: {} }
  end

  def failure
    render status: 401,
           json: { success: false,
                   info: "Login or Logout Failed",
                   data: {} }
  end
end
```

**Registration**

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  respond_to :json

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      sign_in resource

      resource_hash = {
        email: resource.email,
        name: resource.name,
        auth_token: resource.authentication_token,
        external_id: resource.external_id,
        created_at: resource.created_at
      }

      render status: 200,
             json: { success: true,
                     info: "Registered",
                     data: { user: resource_hash } }
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity,
             json: { success: false,
                     info: "Registration failed",
                     data: resource.errors }
    end
  end

  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

devise remove the token authentication strategy, so you should to implement your own token strategy in order to use that guide, I'm dealing with this same problem now, so i started from scratch with warden, check railscast 305 episode for more info, is a pro episode, but i you don't have access, warden's wiki is pretty self explanatory, regards!

Comment: Ah, I actually just solved it by implementing my own login and logout functions. It isn't tough. Devise is still useful for a lot of things, but I decided to take care of the logging in and logging out.